# ¿Como cambio la versión de una librería (jar) en java?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando añadir una librería a un proyecto en java y no me deja funcionar la librería usada debido a que la versión de java en la que fue compilada fue una versión anterior, como hago para compilar dicha librería con java8?

Comment: ¿Cual es la libreria?

Comment: org.red1.chartmaker_3.1.0.201606011145.jar es una libreria de un ERP que se llama Idempiere

Comment: ¿Ya buscaste en su página? Dice que es compatible con Java 8. Aqui esta su código fuente: https://sourceforge.net/projects/idempiere/files/?source=navbar